# MSbotframework finding out which platform is being used

Tags: c#, facebook, skype, botframework

I have created a bot using Microsoft framework with C#. The bot is accessible from multiple platforms (Facebook and skype) and if possible I would like to know which platform each user is using, only I can't seem to find where this data is stored. If anyone can help I would be very grateful.
Thanks in advance. Regards Cuan.

Answer (score 1):

Each `Activity` has a `ChannelId` property which should show where it came from.

For example, you can see the `Activity.ChannelId = 'emulator'` in the emulator.

https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/routing.html

https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/dc/d2f/class_microsoft_1_1_bot_1_1_connector_1_1_activity.html#a14e7a5943c8061a8167f1a8260d4a53a